# Can I use a game to earn "support money"?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, business

Can I use the game to earn the "support money"? Even I not own the game copyright?

For example, I use one game to build and made a screen or some character, then I share it, after that I post a link (e.g.: Paypal, Patreon) which can earn the  "support money", the supporter can send me some money to support me, just like a tip.

**Is that legal?**

It mean I use the game which I not own the copyright, to make some artwork, then I use those artwork to earn the tips and gratuity of fans. Is that legal?

Answer (score 1):

Not owning the game copyright is a key fact, but not the only relevant fact needed to come up with an accurate answer. There may or may not be a license or implied license to use the material, or the use may be "fair use". Using sharing something derived from a game to which you do not own a copyright is on its face a copyright violation. So, unless you fall within an exception to a copyright violation, you are infringing.

The fact that your otherwise infringing work is used to make a profit for yourself, weakens the case that fair use or an implied license authorizes you to do so, but even without receiving any money, you could very well be infringing anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. it make me more careful.

I ask this question, it is because I saw someone post a link about patreon, that link said if you pay $2 per month to that artwork author , you will become the member , and you will get some special image or artwork reward at sometime

it make me wish to create a patreon account to earn some money too , but i worry about the legal problem.

In this case, is that infringing ? or it legal?

Comment: @gary We don't answer specific applications of the law to specific facts on this site and it isn't uncommon in copyright for the legality to be unclear even when you know all of the facts.